# Print uid to screen/browser in Python

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm currently testing mod_wsgi, and trying to print my uid to screen in my browser.

```
import os

uid = os.getuid()

print("uid being used:", uid)

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

expected result was that I would get my uid printed on screen.. so I know what user Mod_wsgi script is running as.. but I am currently printing only Hello World to screen

Comment: It's running as your Apache user.  You won't see that output, because that's printed as part of a process that Apache launches.  Just return your string as the output of the function.

Comment: @TimRoberts Actually I'm testing the mod_wsgi option to run it as a given user instead of apache. However that directive (user=name) has a condition to fail. So that is why I am trying to get uid.. to see what user it is currently running as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on discord, posting it since someone else might find it helpful

```
import os

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = f"Hello World! {os.getuid()}".encode()

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Comment: Just for the record, that's exactly what I said above.